# Modelling triangle using finite difference method error

Tags: matlab, if-statement, geometry

I am trying to model a triangle in a square cell based on its dimension. However, I have some problem with parts of the code, I think it might be the logic behind my programming or over definition with the code itself.

```
% Simulation for triangle

clear all;
clc
clear window 

%% INITIAL PARAMETERS

% Variables
ni=21;                % number of nodes in the cell - x axis
nj=21;                % number of nodes in the cell - y axis
delta_sq=0.3;         % microasperity area density (MAXIMUM 0.433)
u=3.5;                 % slider speed [m/s]
v=0.8;                 % lubricant viscosity [Pas]
F=98.1;                 % applied load [N/m^2]
h_init=20e-06;         % initial guess of film thickness [m]
e_converge=0.0001;     % convergence limit
i_max=500             % maximum number of iterations

% Constants
r_1=600e-06;           % length of half unit cell [m]
P_out=0;              % outer pressure boundary [N/m^2]
P_init=0;               % inner pressure boundary [N/m^2]
P_cav=0;              % cavitation pressure [N/m^2]


%% MESH
R_X=2*r_1;               % length of unit cell - x axis
R_Y=2*r_1;               % length of unit cell - y axis
dX=R_X/(ni-1);          % number of mesh of unit cell - x axis
dY=R_Y/(nj-1);           % number of mesh of unit cell - y axis
X(1)=-R_X/2;             % film thickness at first node - x axis
Y(1)=-R_Y/2;             % film thickness at first node - y axis

for ii=2:(2*ni-1),
    X(ii)=X(ii-1)+dX/2;   % location of intermediate nodes - x axis
end

for jj=2:(2*nj-1),
    Y(jj)=Y(jj-1)+dY/2; % location of intermediate nodes - y axis
end


%% GEOMETRICAL BOUNDARIES

L_triangle=sqrt((delta_sq*16*(r_1)^2)/(sqrt(3)));% side length of triangle

h_step = 5e-06; % step microasperity depth

nHi=max(size(X));
nHj=max(size(Y));

% flat step condition
for ii=1:nHi,
    for jj=1:nHj,
        h(ii,jj)=h_init;
        if X(ii)>(-L_triangle/3) & X(ii)<0;
            if Y(jj)>0;
                if Y(jj)>0 & Y(jj)<((L_triangle+3*X(ii))/(sqrt(3)));
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
                else
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init;
                end
            end
            if Y(jj)<0;
                if Y(jj)>(-L_triangle/(2*sqrt(3))) & Y(jj)<0;
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
                else
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init;
                end
            end
        end
        if X(ii)>0 & X(ii)<(L_triangle/3);
            if Y(jj)>0;
                if Y(jj)>0 & Y(jj)<((L_triangle-3*X(ii))/sqrt(3));
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
                else
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init;
                end
            end
           if Y(jj)<0;
                if Y(jj)>(-L_triangle/(2*sqrt(3))) & Y(jj)<0;
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
                else
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init;
                end
           end
        end
        if X(ii)>0 & X(ii)<(L_triangle/2)    ;
            if Y(jj)<0;
                if Y(jj)>(((-3*X(ii))+L_triangle)/sqrt(3)) & Y(jj)<0;
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
                else
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init;
                end
            end
        end
        if X(ii)>(-L_triangle/2) & X(ii)<0;
            if Y(jj)<0;
                if Y(jj)>(-sqrt(3)*(-3*X(ii)-L_triangle)/3) & Y(jj)<0;
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
                else
                    h(ii,jj)=h_init;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end






%% Pressure

k=1;               
for ii=1:ni,
   for jj=1:nj,
      P(ii,jj,k)=P_init;
end 
end

%Define Coefficients
i=0;
for ii=1:2:nHi,
   i=i+1;
   j=1;
   if ii==1,
      for jj=3:2:nHj-2,
         j=j+1;
            A(i,j)=((6*v*u/dX)*(h(ii+1,jj)-h(nHi-1,jj)))/((h(nHi-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            B(i,j)=((h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2)/((h(nHi-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2); 
            C(i,j)=((h(nHi-1,jj)^3)/dX^2)/((h(nHi-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2); 
            D(i,j)=((h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2)/((h(nHi-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2); 
            E(i,j)=((h(ii,jj-1)^3)/dY^2)/((h(nHi-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2); 
      end
      elseif ii==nHi,
        for jj=3:2:nHj-2,
        j=j+1;
            A(i,j)=((6*v*u/dX)*(h(2,jj)-h(ii-1,jj)))/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(2,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            B(i,j)=((h(2,jj)^3)/dX^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(2,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            C(i,j)=((h(ii-1,jj)^3)/dX^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(2,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            D(i,j)=((h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(2,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            E(i,j)=((h(ii,jj-1)^3)/dY^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(2,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
        end 
        else
     for jj=3:2:nHj-2,
        j=j+1;
            A(i,j)=((6*v*u/dX)*(h(ii+1,jj)-h(ii-1,jj)))/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            B(i,j)=((h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            C(i,j)=((h(ii-1,jj)^3)/dX^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            D(i,j)=((h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
            E(i,j)=((h(ii,jj-1)^3)/dY^2)/((h(ii-1,jj)^3+h(ii+1,jj)^3)/dX^2+(h(ii,jj-1)^3+h(ii,jj+1)^3)/dY^2);
     end 
    end
end

%Solution Kernal
err=1.0;
 while err>e_converge,
%Set the boundary conditions
    for ii=1:ni,
    P(ii,1,k)=P_init;
    P(ii,nj,k)=P_out;
    end
    for i=1:ni,
    for j=2:nj-1,
         if i==1,
            P(i,j,k+1)=(A(i,j)+B(i,j)*P(i+1,j,k)+C(i,j)*P(ni,j,k)+D(i,j)*P(i,j+1,k)+E(i,j)*P(i,j-1,k));
            elseif i==ni,
            P(i,j,k+1)=(A(i,j)+B(i,j)*P(1,j,k)+C(i,j)*P(i-1,j,k)+D(i,j)*P(i,j+1,k)+E(i,j)*P(i,j-1,k));
         else
            P(i,j,k+1)=(-A(i,j)+B(i,j)*P(i+1,j,k)+C(i,j)*P(i-1,j,k+1)+D(i,j)*P(i,j+1,k)+E(i,j)*P(i,j-1,k+1));
         end
            if P(i,j,k+1)<P_cav
               P(i,j,k+1)=P_cav;
            end
    end
    end


% error check point
   PP=max(max(P(:,:,k+1)));
   LIM=0;
   for i=1:ni,
    for j=2:nj-1,
         conv=(P(i,j,k+1)-P(i,j,k))/PP;
         LIM=LIM+conv^2;
    end
   end
   err=1/((ni)*(nj-2))*sqrt(LIM);
   k=k+1;
   if k>i_max,
        k
    break 
    end
end

% Final iteration
for ii=1:ni,
    P(ii,1,k)=P_init;
    P(ii,nj,k)=P_out;
end
for ii=1:ni,
  for jj=1:nj,
      P_solution(ii,jj)=P(ii,jj,k);
  end
end

i=0;
for ii=1:2:nHi,
   i=i+1;
     x_i(i)=X(ii);
    y_j(i)=Y(ii);
end

Maximum_Pressure=max(max(P_solution))
Average_Pressure=mean(mean(P_solution))
Minimum_Pressure=min(min(P_solution))

figure
surf(X,Y,h)

figure
surf(y_j,x_i,P_solution)
```

I have attached the code. The problem lies with the second half of the triangle. I have also attached the basis of my analysis. The problem lies between -s/2 to s/2 of the code. Any hints about the wrong logic of my code or over definition will be appreciated. The cell is a square dimension with 2r1 x 2r1 dimension

when you run the code, the upper half of the triangle looks fine but the lower half isnt. I have attached an image of the analysis behind my code.

http://postimg.org/image/kvn2xqlcx/

Comment: That's a lot of code. What you need to do is to go through it carefully (step-through or set breakpoints) and work out at which point it starts to deviate from what you expect. MATLAB has plenty of built-in tools for this: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/debugging-code.html

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this kind of questions is **discouraged** on stack overflow, since the question regards the debugging of a very specific code and will therefore be of little usefulness to other people in the future.

**Some tips regarding this code**:

1. You shouldn't ignore lint warnings (the orange underlines you see in the MATLAB editor) - they're there for a reason. [There's a known joke on this topic...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235307/3372061)
2. Your code will be much easier to debug if instead of `clear all` you use `clear variables` - the reason for this is that `clear all` clears breakpoints too (which you usually want to keep).
3. I'd suggest adding `close all force` to the initialization to remove any previously open figures.
4. You should really take a look into [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) - this can (usually) help make your code run faster and also be much more readable.

Having said that - this should fix your problem (replace your lines `89-106` by the following):

```
    if X(ii)>0 && X(ii)<(L_triangle/2);
        if Y(jj)<0;
            if Y(jj)>(((-3*X(ii))+L_triangle)/sqrt(3));
                h(ii,jj)=h_init;
            else
                h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
            end
        end
    end
    if X(ii)>(-L_triangle/2) && X(ii)<0;
        if Y(jj)<0;
            if Y(jj)>(-sqrt(3)*(-3*X(ii)-L_triangle)/3);
                h(ii,jj)=h_init;
            else
                h(ii,jj)=h_init+h_step;
            end
        end
    end
    if X(jj)<(-L_triangle/(2*sqrt(3)))
        h(ii,jj)=h_init;
    end
```

You were adding `+h_step` in the wrong place, and also the treatment of the area "under" the triangle was missing.